# Redesign query without using IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like below. This query is working fine but since I have huge amount of data to check, this query running is slower.

Can anybody help me how to optimize this query?

```
SELECT * from trn where concat(comp_id,cus_id) 
IN (select concat(comp_id,cus_id) FROM cus where sid='A0001') 
AND docdate between ('2018-01-01') and ('2018-04-30')
```

Comment: Does MySQL really still have performance issues with `IN` or are you using an old version? Anyway, the query looks strange. Why do you concatenate IDs? Both comp_id 1 / cus_id 11 and comp_id 11 / cus_id 1 would result in 111. Don't you rather want to campare IDs separately? But then, does the table `cus` have a composite primary key consisting of `comp_id,cus_id` or is `cus_id` alone its primary key?

Comment: Your problem is that you use concat.  Functions prevents indexes from being used.  See answer from @dnoeth .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trn t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM cus c 
              WHERE c.sid = 'A0001' AND c.comp_id = t.comp_id AND c.cus_id = t.cus_id
             ) AND
      docdate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-30';
```

Comment: EXISTS will normally not be faster than IN, and since 5.6 it is often slower.  If this EXISTS variant is faster, it is probably because it does not use concat like the original query.  (There is no reason to use concat for IN-variant either)

Answer (score 5):

The `concat` is probably causing those performance problems as it can't use indexes.

But MySQL supports multi-column subqueries, so simply remove it:

```
SELECT * from trn 
where (comp_id,cus_id) IN 
        ( select comp_id,cus_id
          FROM cus 
          where sid='A0001'
        ) 
  AND docdate between ('2018-01-01') and ('2018-04-30')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM trn t 
JOIN cus c ON t.comp_id = c.comp_id AND t.cus_id = c.cus_id
WHERE c.sid='A0001' AND t.docdate BETWEEN ('2018-01-01') AND ('2018-04-30');
```

Comment: Thank You @Darshan Mehta But for some reason my final output with this query is not correct

Comment: @SS Can you add an example?

Comment: You probably need to add DISTINCT, because the `comp_id,cus_id` combination is unique in `cus` but not in `trn`